# Android popBackStack() not restoring previous fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have two fragments MapScreenFragment and SessionSetUpFragment which sub in and out with my activity MapsActivity. I always go to MapScreenFragment first and then there will be a button on MapScreenFragment that calls back to MapsActivity and replaces the current fragment with the SessionSetUpFragment. So the fragment manager stack should have the SessionSetUpFragment then the MapScreenFragment. When I hit the android back button on the SessionSetUpFragment it shows a blank screen and the MapScreenFragment's onCreateView() or onResume() never gets called. Another android back button call will then close the app. How do I get the MapScreenFragment to resume?

**Edit:**
If I change

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack("sessFrag", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

to

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

The problem still resides, but I have one additional blank back screen to go through before the app closes

[image]
[image]

MapScreenFramget.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateView"); //Never gets called
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onResume"); //Never gets called
    super.onResume();
}
```

MapsActivity.java:

```
 @Override
 public void logIn(){
     MapScreenFragment mapFrag = new MapScreenFragment();
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, mapFrag).addToBackStack("mapFrag").commit();
 }

 @Override
 public void sessionSetUp(){
     SessionSetUpFragment sessFrag = new SessionSetUpFragment();
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, sessFrag).addToBackStack("sessFrag").commit();
 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1) + " Popped! " + (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1) + " stacks left!");

        getFragmentManager().popBackStack("sessFrag", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: have only super.onBackPressed(); in the onBackPressed() method and remove everything and check

Comment: @krishna Then the app just closes on back button press. I need to check if the fragment exists on the back stack and pop it off if so. In my case, it is poping something off the stack but it doesn't seem to be/load the mapFrag

Comment: The thing is if you add a fragment to backstack you dont have to check if it exists or not . onBackpressed it will pop the stored fragment from backstack

Comment: @krishna I got what you are saying.  When I open the app back up. it automatically goes to the map, so maybe it is working but just closing the app immediately

Comment: I am  a little confused about how this backstack with fragments really work. So as a work around I dont save my fragments in backstack and override onBackPressed and replace my existing fragment with the desired fragment

Comment: @krishna Do you just save all your fragments and replace them over and over again? Does this screw anything up?

Comment: No it works fine I dont save any see this https://github.com/ktv205/ThreeFragmentActivity/blob/master/src/com/example/threefragmentactivity/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Since `MapScreenFragment` is your first fragment, you might want to try calling `add()` instead of `replace()` in your `login()` method. And don't add it to the backstack. Adding `MapScreenFragment` to the backstack causes the empty space that you see.

Next, your `sessionSetUp()` method looks fine.
As you have already added the `SessionSetUpFragment` to the backStack, you don't need to override the `onBackPressed()`. This has always worked for me.

Comment: This almost works, but the app closes immediated upon a backpress. Although when I open the app back up, it is in the right spot.

Comment: See this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions Is ther anything different you're doing? This should simply work

Comment: Keep in mind the `super.onBackPressed()` that might be called when you do not want to.